# C# Performance gain returning a Nullable Type from a SqlDataReader

Tags: c#, performance, sqldatareader, nullable

I have a simple method that returns a Nullable Int32 from a DataReader rather than the built in GetInt32.

I am calling this method many many times and have one situation where any time I can shave off of it would be beneficial.

Can anyone suggest any alternative and faster ways of getting a nullable Int32 out of the DataReader?

```
private Int32? GetNullableInt32(SqlDataReader dataReader, int fieldIndex)
{
    return !dataReader.IsDBNull(fieldIndex) ? 
                dataReader.GetInt32(fieldIndex) : (Int32?)null;
}
```

Comment: I think that's about as good as you're going to get.

Comment: I remember reading the IsDBNull check was slow.
This runs 5 million times in about 2 seconds. I also have similar methods for all the other types. Even a 10% gain on this method will reduce the time massively.

Comment: @Robin Day I would first profile to look for other performance detrements first - the percentage gain vs effort, I would argue for this, is going to be one of the lowest you see.

Comment: @Adam: I have profiled every method call and there are other areas that are being improved. However, these methods are taking up about 15-20% of the total run time as they are called so many times. So micro-optimisation or not, I need to shave as much time off of this call as possible.

Comment: If they are called a lot, then presumably you are performing a relative amount of database selects?  Or are you re-calling onto the same result set?  If its the latter, an alternative would be to read the result-set once and cache that read.  If it's the former, then you've got a very fast database and network :-)

Comment: Alternatively again, replace nulls with actual values in places where this is possible - to avoid the null check all together.

Comment: @Adam: It is one large select that gets all the data. This is then cached which is used for the majority of use. However, there are certain user actions that require them to see up to date data. This is currently taking around 6 seconds. My goal is to get this down to 3 seconds and then I get a case of beers. So every 100ms counts.

Comment: @Adam: I am looking at removing the nullable types completely. There are not many cases where they are needed and so I should be able to re-factor those places accordingly. That might help a lot.

Comment: Well, if beer is the reward then plug away mate!  I'd also make that method static otherwise FxCop will whinge at you lol

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I *seem* to recall that it can sometimes by faster to get the value as an object and then check if that's DBNull.

```
private Int32? GetNullableInt32(SqlDataReader dataReader, int fieldIndex)
{
    object value = dataReader.GetValue(fieldIndex);
    return value is DBNull ? (Int32?) null : (Int32) value;
}
```

It's at least worth a try. Note that this is assuming you can unbox straight to an `int`... I don't know for sure whether that's correct, but it'll be easy to see.

Now there's another approach which is somewhat less safe - it will return null for any non-integer value, even if the field is actually a string, for example:

```
private Int32? GetNullableInt32(SqlDataReader dataReader, int fieldIndex)
{
    return dataReader.GetValue(fieldIndex) as Int32?;
}
```

I've previously written about "as" with nullable types not being as fast as I'd expect, but this may be a slightly different case... again, it's worth having a go.

However, I'd be really surprised if this is genuinely a bottleneck... surely getting the data from the database in the first place is going to be far more expensive. Do you have benchmarks for this?

Comment: I do have benchmarks for this, and yes, this is by no means the slowest part of the call, however, I have done all I can in getting the data back faster and now just looking to shave the last couple of seconds off. I am running tests against these two methods now and will post the results.

Comment: +1 doubtful its the bottleneck also - very rarely does network or I/O out-perform a CPU.

Comment: On profiling for 5 million calls on each method.
My method runs in 998ms
Your first method runs in 1169ms
Your second method runs in 898ms

That's a 10% gain and good enough for me! Thanks!

Comment: Could the first method be made faster by changing `value is DBNull` to `value == DBNull.Value`?

Answer (score 2):

The code you want to optimize (the `?:`) will be insignificant compared to the surrounding I/O.

So, it's not going to get any faster.

Comment: +1 indeed, sounds like a micro-optimization at best, the OP also mentions in the comments that it runs 5 million times in 2 seconds... sounds fast enough to me.